# Playing external MP3 file (without fully loading it) on iOS using Phonegap Media

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova, html5-audio

I'm currently building an MP3 app for iOS and Android that plays external MP3 files. The problem is that my MP3 files are very big (usually over 100MB) each. I am using Phonegap's (3.0) Media plugin and everything works perfectly fine, except that it takes very long to initially play the file. I came to the conclusion that this is happening because Phonegap downloads the entire file before playing it. How do I tell it to start playing before the file is fully downloaded?

When the file is accessed through a regular desktop browser like Chrome, the file plays almost instantly, so I know the internet connection is not the issue here. Smaller files (around 5MB) plays almost instantly on the APP as well.

Comment: Use a desktop streaming application; [How to Stream an Mp3](http://www.ehow.com/how_4894560_stream-mp.html)

Comment: That is an option, but if I take that route, I would not be able to allow the user to seek on the track or know the track's length, right? The service is meant to be more of a on-demand thing, where you can select and play a track, almost as if it was already on their phone. Any idea how Last.fm or Pandora do it?